# strcmp() not working for char *array and char const comparison

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am facing problem with following code. I want to compare the input words. The strcmp is not returning 0 for same char strings. It is pretty straightforward problem but I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

```
#include<string.h> 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char message[255];
    fgets(message,254,stdin);
    char *command[2];   
    char *p;
    int i=0;

    for(p=strtok(message," ");p!=NULL;p=strtok(NULL," "))
    {
        command[i]=p;
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",command[i]);
    }

    int dif=strcmp(command[0],"get");   
    fprintf(stderr,"dif is:%d\n",dif);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never increment `i` in your `for` loop. Thus, a pointer to *every* word in your message is written to `command[0]`.

Try this:

```
for(p=strtok(message," ");p!=NULL;p=strtok(NULL," "))
{
    command[i]=p;
    fprintf(stderr, "command[%d]==%s\n", i, command[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

But note that the fixed (and relatively small) size of your `command` array is a bug waiting to happen. Consider what happens to your 2-length array if the user enters 3 or more words.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it worked. It was my silly mistake.

Comment: A third (unchecked) token will cause havoc.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Very true. I've added a warning to my answer. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to expand on that warning.